# What is the difference between PHP header and Javascript window.location?

Tags: php, javascript, header, window.location

So yeah this came to mind randomly when I was teaching someone how to redirect their page. I wasn't really sure what the main difference was... Is there a reason you would use one over the other? I guess if you are not coding in PHP, you would have to use the Javascript `window.location` to redirect but would you ever use `window.location` over PHP `header` if you were developing in PHP? I feel they have very similar functions but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: [PHP Redirect Vs JavaScript Redirect](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2009/10/php-redirect-vs-javascript-redirect.html)

Comment: @ZoltanToth thank you so much for that article! answered my question exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser will process the header redirect right away, whereas the Javascript redirect will not be executed until the page has loaded (or at least enough of it to run the Javascript). Also, it will be the Javascript engine executing the redirect instead of the browser itself.

Doing it via the header will perform better. (slightly anyway...)

Comment: Is there ever a reason why you would not want to process the redirect right away? I feel if you are going to do an auto-redirect, going with your answer, wouldn't `header` always be the better option? Or are there times you would want to send information first and then redirect which would make `window.location` more appealing?

Comment: `window.location` is useful if the redirect is being triggered based on activity on the page. If all you want is an "instant redirect", use the header.

Comment: @aug And obviously doing it with the header can happen whether Javascript is enabled or not (which may or may not be important for you)

Answer (score 1):

PHP's server-side header can send other headers then only `Location`. Javascripts client-side `window.location` can be used to read, inspect, and alter (parts of the) current url, including hash. Really, they can do quite different stuff, and about their *only* overlap is both being able to redirect.